# Building for Windows XP fails even the special toolchain

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp

I'm building a C++ project into a 32-bit .exe with `Visual Studio 2013`, with specified **Platform Toolset:** `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)`

When I attempt to run the new .exe on a machine with Windows XP, I get an `.exe is not a valid Win32 application` error.

What else must I do to make it run on XP?

Also I must add two constraints that can not change right now:

1. the compiler has to be `MSVC`
2. I can't use an earlier version than the one in `Visual Studio 2013` (`v120 & v120_xp`)

What else can I do?

Comment: Well, changing the toolset did not work.  Most obvious mistake is changing it for the Debug configuration but forgetting to do so for the Release configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click Start, and then click Run.
2. Type "command.com" , and then press Enter. (A DOS window opens.)
3. Type the following:

   ```
    "cd\"

    "cd \windows"
   ```

   Press Enter after typing each one.
4. Type copy "regedit.exe regedit.com" and then press Enter.
5. Type "start regedit.com" and then press Enter.
6. Navigate to and select the key:

   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command
7. In the right pane, double-click the (Default) value.
8. Delete the current value data, and then type:

   "%1" %*

   Tip: Type the characters: quote-percent-one-quote-space-percent-asterisk.
9. Close Regedit utility.

Comment: could you elaborate, I'm not sure what this does exactly

Comment: This fixes a broken shell association, which has different symptoms.